# jquery autocomplete with hidden data cant get id and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, autocomplete

I am using `Jquery.autocomplete.js`. I  can get term and output sent using json encode, but I can't get the value in one textbox and ID in a hidden textbox.

1. **script:**

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $().ready(function() {
   $(".autocomplete_user").autocomplete("/get_user_name", {
       minChars: 0,
       max: 12,
       autoFill: true,
       mustMatch: true,
       matchContains: false,
       scrollHeight: 220,
       formatItem: function(row, i, total) {
           return row.value;
       },
       formatResult: function(row) {
           return row.value;
       }
   });
   $('.autocomplete_user').result(function(event, data, formatted) {
       $('#user_id_val').val(!data ? '' : data.id);
   });
   ```

   });

2. **view:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-md autocomplete_user" name="receiver_name" value="" placeholder=" Type Here">
<input type="hidden" name="receiver_id" id="user_id_val" value="" />
```

3. **I can get output like this**

   [{id: "131", value: "murugan"}]

Comment: Macha, adhaan value varudhey!

Comment: value varuthu but adha 2 textbox ku id and value thaniya send pana mudila..

Comment: Try `JSON.parse` and then use `[0]` or something? Fiddle pannu!

Comment: also textboxla array typela value show panudhu..pa..enaku konjam jquery array concept weak

Comment: ok wait ...i will do praveen